# Is the value of crypo currencies determined against the US dollar?

Tags: currency, cryptocurrency, currency-exchange

For example, for a european investor is EUR/Bitcoin implied directly from of USD/Bitcoin or are traded as 2 different markets?

Comment: Traded where? There is no universal market.

Comment: The value of a good can be *measured* relative to any currency or other good or service you choose, but it's not *defined* relative to any of them.

Comment: what I mean is, is the USD/crypto the most liquid pair like for normal currencies eg USDBRL determines all the other XXXBRL?